# Count of Element how many times exists in a list of lists networkx simplepath

Tags: python, list, networkx

I have a list of lists like

```
[['n2', 'n3', 'n6', 'n5', 'n4'], ['n2', 'n6', 'n5', 'n4']]
```

I want to count how many times an item (e.g.`n3` once) doesn't exist in this list of lists.
It is easy to make a loop to check over this but it takes time when I have many lists.

```
count = 0
for path in paths:
    if key not in path:
        count += 1
```

Is there a way to make it faster without a loop?

I tried this approach but when it finds it returns `True` right away.

```
res1 = any(elem_to_find in sublist for sublist in ini_list)
```

PS. I am using `paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=src_node, target=trg_node)` to get this list of lists. In case of a shorter way with this library would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

One short solution I can think of is to abuse `sum`.

```py
paths = [['n2', 'n3', 'n6', 'n5', 'n4'], ['n2', 'n6', 'n5', 'n4']]
key = 'n3'

# This returns 1
sum(key not in path for path in paths)
```

Comment: Thanks but it basically does the same. I can't get any performance improvement with this.